# How to determine whether a solvent is polar or unpolar?

Tags: polarity

I'm going to get different solvents with different bonding types (polar and non polar) and put different solutes with an "unknown" bond type to test whether or not the solute is polar or non polar The question is, can I improve this in anyway or take it further than I've already described. It sounds too easy to me and I want to take it a step (if not a few steps) further.

Comment: Is this project for school students? if students have prior knowledge then you can explain things like eutectic mixtures and azeotropes

Answer (score 1):

One thing you should definitely do is a *control* experiment where you check some known with certainty solutes as to their polarity. This will establish a baseline hypothesis experimentally; i.e. you've been taught that "like dissolves like", but you should demonstrate this to yourself experimentally. Once you do this, then your testing with unknown solutes is more meaningful because you then have similar experimental observations.

And you may find some surprises when you do this! For example, *soaps* are interesting compounds because they are largely nonpolar molecules with polar "ends". This is why they can dissolve oil (nonpolar) in water (polar), and thus is why soap "cleanses".